# Is this a drain-pipe?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, drain, drainage, water-damage

I am about to install a water heater in our condo. This is inside the house so I want to be careful about possible leaks. I am putting a drain pan underneath it and need to connect it to a drain somewhere.

I noticed this pipe in the back wall of the water heater closet and am wondering if this is a drain pipe that I can connect the drip pan to. Any idea if it is or what is a good way to test?

We just bought the condo and the previous water heater did not have a drain pan (causing it to leak - long story). I have reached out to the HOA but not sure if they'd know either.

PS: adding a couple more pictures. We had to remove the dry-wall due to leaks from the old heater. You can see the pipe on the bottom of the platform on which there is the AC unit.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe, but maybe not.  You will want to find out where it goes before you make any plans for using it.

Comment: I suspect it would be more correct to say You will want to find out where it **comes from** before you make any plans for using it. It looks liked the drain end of an exciting overflow drain.

Comment: If it is near an AC unit, this might be run-off from the condenser. Look for AC or some other cooler nearby.

Comment: Yes it is right underneath the AC unit. The wall it is sticking out from is the platform for the AC unit. I will try to find out from the HOA if they have any of the plans.

Comment: Added a second picture to OP showing the pipe in relation to the AC unit.

Comment: that right angle copper pipe used to be connected to the T&P blowoff, so it is likely a drain. Too high to drain the floor though.

Comment: So here is what I am thinking - install water heater on a stand higher than right angle copper pipe. That is definitely a drain as it was connected to the T&P valve in the previous heater. In the new install, have the T&P drain into the drip pan and connect the drip pan to the drain. If the pedestal for the heater/drip-pan is higher than the right angled drain pipe, this should work right?